# How can I cv2.imshow large size images?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to `cv2.imshow` my images for perspective transformation.

But, my image is very big, so I cannot see the whole picture:

[image]

How could I fix this problem?

The below is my code:

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

image_path = "1.jpg"
filename, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(img_path))
ori_img = cv2.imread(img_path)


src = []

# mouse callback handler
def mouse_handler(event, x, y, flags, param):
  if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
    img = ori_img.copy()

    src.append([x, y])

    for xx, yy in src:
      cv2.circle(img, center=(xx, yy), radius=5, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=-1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

    cv2.imshow('img', img)

    # perspective transform
    if len(src) == 4:
      src_np = np.array(src, dtype=np.float32)

      width = max(np.linalg.norm(src_np[0] - src_np[1]), np.linalg.norm(src_np[2] - src_np[3]))
      height = max(np.linalg.norm(src_np[0] - src_np[3]), np.linalg.norm(src_np[1] - src_np[2]))

      dst_np = np.array([
        [0, 0],
        [width, 0],
        [width, height],
        [0, height]
      ], dtype=np.float32)

      M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src=src_np, dst=dst_np)
      result = cv2.warpPerspective(ori_img, M=M, dsize=(width, height))

      cv2.imshow('result', result)
      cv2.imwrite(r'projetive_image/%s_result%s' % (filename, ext), result)

# main
cv2.namedWindow('img')
cv2.setMouseCallback('img', mouse_handler)

cv2.imshow('img', ori_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Just resize the image before displaying it?

Comment: normally it can zoom image with mouse wheel but I don't know if it can make it smaller. But you can always use `cv2.resize()` before you show it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sorry for the spam, I'm going through old questions and modifying format, fixing broken links, and adding tags

Comment: @nathancy Typically people try to keep it to 5 or 10 at a time, to not swamp the active question list. But yes, editing old questions to improve the collection is always useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of **resizing your image** before displaying, you can also **resize the window**, that displays the image, by using [`cv2.resizeWindow`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga9e80e080f7ef33f897e415358aee7f7e). Therefore, you need to set the `cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL` [WindowFlag](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#gabf7d2c5625bc59ac130287f925557ac3) in your [`cv2.namedWindow`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5afdf8410934fd099df85c75b2e0888b) call.

That'd be a minimal example:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.random.randint(0, 255, (4000, 3000, 3), np.uint8)

cv2.namedWindow('img', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow('img', 800, 600)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
OpenCV:      4.2.0
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4):

Before displaying the image, you could simply downsize the image using [`cv2.resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) or if you wanted to maintain aspect ratio, you can use [`imutils.resize`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils#resizing). Another method is to simply save the image using `cv2.imwrite` then open it in your system's native image viewer.

```
import cv2
import imutils

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')

# Downsize without aspect ratio
image1 = cv2.resize(image, (500,500), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

# Downsize and maintain aspect ratio
image2 = imutils.resize(image, width=800)

cv2.imshow('image1', image1)
cv2.imshow('image2', image2)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Resize can lose the information. So i want to avoid it

Comment: As far as I know you can't fully display an image larger than your screen resolution. If you're afraid that resizing will lose information (it will), you can make a copy of the image then resize on the copy. Think of this copied image as the "display only" image. Your original image will be untouched. For instance, if your image frame is called `image`, you can make a copy with: `display_image = image.copy()` then resize on the `display_image`

Comment: @Seunghyeon but the suggestion is to only use resize for displaying purposes. You could work on (or save) the full-sized image for further processing with no problem...